# TCL crashing when on including source multiple times

Tags: tcl

I have one receive.tcl script which contains only single proc which consist of some 1KLOC

```
puts "DEBUG_1"
proc Receive { arg1 arg2} {
puts "DEBUG_2"
... TCL Code
}
puts "DEBUG_3"
```

Now i need to use this proc Receive at so many different scripts; 
Lets say in; `1.tcl` `2.tcl` `3.tcl` and so on and all these `1.tcl` `2.tcl` are getting called from Master(`Master.tcl`).

Is it neccessary to include/write `source PATH/receive.tcl` in every `1.tcl` `2.tcl` and so on; to use `Receive`.

OR

I can call "source PATH/receive.tcl" from some Master(`Master.tcl`)script and it can be used further in any `1.tcl` `2.tcl` and so on without including anything separately; will TCL interpreter store/remember this proc Receive and can be used in any further scripts?

**Problem :** When I "source `$PATH/receive.tcl` in every `1.tcl` `2.tcl` and so on and not in `Master.tcl`; `Master.tcl` contains `source $PATH/1.tcl` `source $PATH/2.tcl` and so on; then i am executing `Master.tcl`.

1. In First iteration `1.tcl` gets successfully executed;
2. Interpreter will go in `receive.tcl`; it's printing `DEBUG_1` and `DEBUG_3` and further `proc Receive` is used by `1.tcl` successfully.
3. but when interpreter moves to `2.tcl` it finds `source $PATH/receive.tcl`
4. Interpreter goes to `receive.tcl`
5. and TCL gets crashing again and  again; means i can see only `DEBUG_1` only; segmentation fault after that.

Comment: By “crash” do you mean “generates an error message that describes what the problem is”?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first a few things: Tcl should not crash (if you don't use any 3rd party dlls). If it does, consider [creating a bug report](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=10894&atid=110894).

1kloc sounds bad to me, maybe something else is better. I think you try to parse some input and invoke different things, if this is the case, take a look at  the [`interp`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1477), one of my favorite gems in Tcl.

**To answer your question:**
You can source the file in the master and use it from other files that are later sourced.

In your case (where the only purpose of that file is to be called by other files), you could create a package. The biggest problems when creating a package is to decide where to install it (use `TCL_LIBRARY` enviroment variable, pick a directory in `$auto_path`, add the folder to the `$auto_path` in your code). Look into the [Tcl Tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl31.html) for some reference.

Comment: I'd note that getting an error message (e.g., about infinite loops) is _not_ a crash. It's just a recoverable error message that you can `catch` if you want. Reporting that as a bug in Tcl itself isn't going to give you a particularly kind response!

Comment: I don't count segfaults as recoverable error. Pure Tcl should never yield a segfault.